# Running SETX from Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, shell

At the moment, I am building a program in Visual Basic 2010 Professional. When a button is pressed, I need the following to run...

```
Shell(CMD.exe)
        SendKeys.Send("SETX CCDeviceID " & DeviceID & "")
        SendKeys.Send()
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        SendKeys.Send("exit")
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        Shell("C:\Python27\python C:\FusionTechnology\stage1.py")
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
        SendKeys.Send("exit")
```

and this works, but the python script starts running before the SETX command completes. Any ideas on how I can wait for the SETX to run and finish before executing the next command?

Thanks!

Comment: Add some commands to check and see if the environment variable is set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the System.Diagnostics.Process class, something like this;

```
Dim vProcess As Diagnostics.Process
vProcess = Process.Start("SETX.exe", "CCDeviceID " & DeviceID)
vProcess.WaitForExit()

vProcess = Process.Start("C:\Python27\python", "C:\FusionTechnology\stage1.py")
```

Saves messing about with commands in the shell one line at a time!

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work... could you include an example?

Comment: You mean aside from the example above?  What exactly can't you get to work?  The code above _should_ replicate the example you gave in the question.  SETX simply writes to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` in the registry - it might be quicker to just use the `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` namespace if you have the permissions.

Comment: I have just ran the example I gave you, and it writes the 'CCDeviceID' variable to the registry.  The second process isn't started until after the first one exits - as designed.  If you put some messageboxes or Debug.Writelines in the code, or just run it through the debugger, you should be able to see it all working 1 step at a time.

Comment: Sorry, 2 buttons had the same name somehow and I got confused! It works perfect... thanks!